# transfer file through serial using python xmodem like tera term xmodem

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial, teraterm, xmodem

Is it possible to implement a sending method using python (xmodem package ?) that works like tera term transfer -> xmodem-crc ?
From what i read from the python xmodem module docs it seems we need another python script at the other serial end to receive the packages.
This should not be needed in my case since there is already a program listening to packages. Tera term is capable of doing this but it is manual.